# Use one terminal instance for many do shell scripts?

Tags: shell, ssh, applescript

So, I need to make an AppleScript to ssh into my mint headless server. I don't need to transfer files, just run commands. The issue is, when I ssh with one do shell script, it is in a separate instance than the others. Also, bonus if I don't have to use keystrokes and keep the terminal in front.

*Edit: It would help if you guys told me why you're downvoting this post.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you want but with `Terminal.app` you can do that:

```
set shellScript to "echo" & space & quoted form of "Test Message"

 tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    try
        if (exists tab 1 of window 1) then
            do script with command shellScript in front window
        else
            do script with command shellScript
        end if
    on error
        beep
    end try
end tell
```

Above code executes `shellScript` in the front window or in a new window when no window is open. Hope it helps.

**ADDITION**
I think there is no `AppleScript` script command to `hide` an `application`.
With `System Events` we can do a `keystroke`, so let's do `cmd-h` which hides an application:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Terminal" to set frontmost to true
    -- delay 0.25 -- in case it does not work
    keystroke "h" using command down
end tell
```

I don't know how Terminal.app will behave with hiding and doing scripts but you will find out.

Or put the Terminal-Window in another Finder Space.

Comment: Okay, this does do the first part of what I wanted, but is there any way to keep the terminal hidden?

Comment: I added something for that but it's probably not so great. Also, check out Terminal's Preferences, may be you can compose a profile that fits your needs.

Comment: Okay, but I was looking for a way to hide the terminal while it is running commands so that it is not visible.

Comment: When you run the hiding code it certainly hides the application but i assume it gets visible again when you do the shell script. May be you can execute the hide command in Terminal, using osascript.

Comment: (… and, of course, in case you copied the whole script, remove the "activate" after "tell app…" )